# Path issue with passing a command from Autohotkey to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, autohotkey

```
Mypath := "C:\temp\example1.txt"
Run, powershell -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

The above works just fine, content is copied to the clipboard by PowerShell but when I do the same thing but with a file that has a space in its file name it fails to run in PowerShell.

Running below

```
Mypath := "C:\temp\example 1.txt"
Run, powershell -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

I get this error in PowerShell

```
Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1.txt'.
```

I have also tried to use double quotes on each side and use Autohotkeys escape symbol like so:

```
Mypath = "`"C:\temp\example 1.txt`""
Run, powershell -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

As well as

```
Mypath = ""C:\temp\example 1.txt""
Run, powershell -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

But on both occasions, PowerShell throws this error;

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
```

What am I doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how AutoHotKey works but, have you tried enclosing your variable in a set of quotes as well? So, something like: `Get-Content -Path \`"%MyPath%\`"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite weird but it is possible to get it working. It's really one escape hell.
Lets go through what's wrong with each of your attempts.

---

```
Mypath := "C:\temp\example 1.txt"
Run, powershell -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

Here you're **not** using the legacy syntax to assign a value to the variable `Mypath`, as you should.
It's a good thing to not be using the legacy syntax anymore.
However, since you're not using the legacy syntax, and are using the modern assigning operator `:=`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetExpression.htm)</sup>, you don't have any extra quotes `"` around the string.
So you're executing PowerShell with the following switches:
`-command "get-content -path C:\temp\example 1.txt | Set-Clipboard"`.
And as you were able to guess, this is wrong because your filename is not quoted.

---

```
Mypath = "`"C:\temp\example 1.txt`""
Run, powershell -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

Here you're again using legacy syntax. So any string is interpreted literally. Therefore, firstly there is no reason to try to escape the quotes `"`, and secondly you [don't escape quotes in AHK with `` ` ``](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm).
So, in this attempt you're executing PowerShell with the following switches:
`-command "get-content -path ""C:\temp\example 1.txt"" | Set-Clipboard"`.
And this is no good, because first `""`s get evaluated to a single `"`, and then you have
`-command "get-content -path "C:\temp\example 1.txt" | Set-Clipboard"`
which has unescaped quotes `"` inside another quotes, so that's no good.

---

```
Mypath = ""C:\temp\example 1.txt""
Run, powershell -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

And then here you have the exact same issue as in the previous one. Because, as we established, you don't escape quotes with `` ` ``. This code is the exact same as the one above.

---

#### So, how should it be done?

You either need one more pair of escaped quotes `"` around the file path, or then just use a single quote for the inner quotes.

---

So in **legacy syntax** you'd want either:

```
Mypath = """"C:\temp\example 1.txt""""
Run, powershell -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

or

```
Mypath = 'C:\temp\example 1.txt'
Run, powershell -noexit -command "get-content -path %Mypath% | Set-Clipboard"
```

---

And in the **modern expression syntax**, you'd want either:

```
Mypath := """""""""C:\temp\example 1.txt"""""""""
Run, % "powershell -noexit -command ""get-content -path " Mypath " | Set-Clipboard"""
```

or

```
Mypath := "'C:\temp\example 1.txt'"
Run, % "powershell -noexit -command ""get-content -path " Mypath " | Set-Clipboard"""
```

Comment: So I had sometime to sit down and work through your comment and was finally able to work on my code, in short. using your answer I was able to get it to work.

But I think you did allot more service for me than just solving that single issue and I would like to thank you allot for that. What you explained are issues I’ve been grappling with since I started learning general programming and it was just really nice to have someone explain it to me in such a humble way, sincerely thank you.

PS: Apparently I am too new to do vote on answers. Never the less. its the best answer.